# Deserialization of ulong failing for .NET Core

Tags: json.net, .net-core, json-deserialization

I'm doing a very simple deserialization of `ulong`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var data = ulong.MaxValue;
            var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ulong>(serialized);
            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

In a normal console application, this works fine. But when doing this in a .NET Core Console Application, it fails with the following error:

> JSON integer 18446744073709551615 is too large or small for an Int64. Path '', line 1, position 20.

It seems to me that this is trying to convert to a `long` instead of a `ulong`. What is the matter here? Is this a bug in JSON .NET or .NET Core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a bug in Newtonsoft.Json that will be fixed started from `9.0.2` (related [issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/pull/892)).

I have checked your code in my project and after adding direct referenced to `"Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.2-beta001"` in `project.json` the problem is gone.